# Performance Testing MSMQ Server

Tags: performance, windows-server-2003, msmq

Has anyone done any sort of performance tests against MSMQ?

We have a solution in prod environment where errors are added to a MSMQ for distribution to databases or event monitors.

We need to test the capacity of this system but not sure how to start.

Anyone know any tools or have any tips?

Answer (score 1):

try overloading it with a test program and see where it balks/fails

[analgous to "destructive testing" in materials engineering]

Answer (score 1):

[QueueExplorer](http://www.cogin.com/) has "Mass send" option which could be used to send bunch of messages to a queue, with or without delay between them. I know it's not a fully automated stress test, but running it from few instances or even few machines, could generate significant stress load.

Disclaimer: I'm author of QueueExplorer.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I was thinking that was hoping for a more public tool.